# Prevent empty pages when using \newpage

Tags: sectioning, page-breaking

I’m currently trying to build a tex template for a class of reports. These are mostly generated and shouldn’t require human intervention to fix oddities before they go out.

Each section should start on a new page, so I added (using `titleformat` from the `titlesec` package)

```tex
\titleformat{\section}{\newpage % some other formatting stuff
}
```

The issue is now if the content from the previous section fills the entire previous page, I have *two* page breaks in a row ending up with an empty (save for header/footer) page in the middle. Is there any way to prevent that from happening?

Comment: a `\newpage` at an automatic page break would normally be discarded, so presumably the `\titleformat`  command (that you have not defined here) is adding this at the wrong place, probably after the vertical space above the heading.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle the `\titleformat` is from `titlesec`. I’ll add that to the question. I didn’t know there was automatic vertical space above the heading, that gives me a hint of where to look, thanks!

Comment: `\newpage` normaly does `\vfil\break`, i.e. `\vfil\penalty-10000`. When you put such items to an empty page then TeX discards them. It means TeX doesn't create empty page in such case. Maybe you put something else before `\newpage`, but people here cannot know what. Because you didn't show full example.